# Unable to include a module in a fortran program

Tags: module, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile with a fortran program that uses another module. For some reason when I try to compile it I keep getting the error:

```
testinc.f95:5:17:

    5 |     type(linreg) :: lr
      |                 1
Error: Derived type ‘linreg’ at (1) is being used before it is defined
```

Here is the module linalg.f95

```
module linalg
    implicit none
    
    type linreg
        integer :: n
        double precision :: m
        double precision :: b
        double precision :: Sxx
        double precision :: Sxy
        double precision :: Se
        double precision :: Syy
        double precision :: Sm
        double precision :: Sb
        double precision :: r
    end type
    
end module
```

and here is the calling program testinc.f95

```
program testinc
    use linalg
    implicit none
    
    type(linreg) :: lr
    
    print *,'done'
end program
```

This is the line I use to compile

```
gfortran -fcheck=all -o testinc.exe linalg.f95 testinc.f95
```

linalg.f95 and testinc.f95 are both in the same folder.

I am using gfortran compiler on ubuntu 22.04.03 (It also won't compile on a raspberry pi either).
I have used the full version of linalg.f95 many times before, so I don't understand why it won't compile properly now.

Comment: Please always use [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. First delete all .mod files from the directory. The fact that you had different versions of the file is suggesting some mess there. Please note that tje extension .f95 is bot a great idea, I suggest using .f90 for all Fortran free-form files. Some compilers will not recognize .f95.

Comment: Works for me if I follow your instructions. This suggests as @VladimirFГероямслава says it is something in your local environment. probably picking up a module called linalg that *does not* have a type linreg in ti